# How to inferenciate the Van Der Pol equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have been reading the Van Der Pol article, On "Relaxations Oscilations", 1926, and i want to obtain the Van  Der Pol equation from the general damped equation :

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}-\alpha \dfrac{dx}{dt}+\omega^2x=0$$

and obtain,

$$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}-\dfrac{\alpha}{\omega}(1-v^2)\dfrac{dv}{dt}+v=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Van Der Pol usses the equation,

$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}-(\alpha-3\gamma x^2) \dfrac{dx}{dt}+\omega^2x=0$$

and the transformation, 
$$\omega t=t' $$,
$$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha}{3\gamma}}v$$

to do it, but i can't obtain (1) using that susbsitution, i don't get how to to change the variable of differentiation, any help? Thanks!

Comment: well, in the article he writed $\omega t=t'$

Comment: $\omega t=t'\implies dx/dt=(dx/dt')\cdot(dt'/dt)=\omega\cdot dx/dt'$. Do the same for $d^2x/dt^2$, plug it in, and see what you get.

Comment: thanks i get it!